# Creating an array of arrays in perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

How can I create an array of arrays in `perl` and access each of the member arrays with an appropriate index.

Currently I'm using a one dimensional array, updating it at each iteration and printing:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$size;$i++)
{
  @words = @synsets[$i]->words;
  print "@words\n"
}
```

But since at the next step i want to perform further operations, I want to access arrays corresponding to each "synset".
Could someone please tell me how i could do that?

Comment: you can write the C-style `for` loop more idiomatically in Perl as `foreach my $i (0 .. $size -1 )` which is arguably easier to read. (and instead of `$size - 1` you can use `$#synsets` which gives the index of the last item in @synsets)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small self-contained files to demonstrate the basics.  Edit to suit :-)

[`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDumper) helps with visualizing data structures - a great learning tool.

The `[]` acts as an ["anonymous array constructor"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References).  You can read more about that with `perldoc perlref` (or follow the previous link). Sometimes you have to explain something to someone else before you can be even somewhat sure you understand it yourself, so bear with me ;-)

```
use 5.10.0 ;
use Data::Dump;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @AoA ;

#my $file = "testdata.txt";
#open my ($fh), "<", "$file" or die "$!";
#while  (<$fh>) {
while  (<DATA>) {
  my @line = split ; 
  push @AoA, [@line] ;
}

say for @AoA;   # shows array references
say @{$AoA[0]}[0] ;  # dereference an inner element
foreach my $i (0..$#AoA)
{
 say "@{$AoA[$i]}[2..4]" ; # prints columns 3-5 
} 

dd (@AoA) ;   # dump the data structure we created ... just to look at it.

__DATA__
1 2 3 0 8 8
4 5 6 0 7 8
7 8 9 0 6 7
```

Comment: I claim no authority on their use but I'm finding references and anonymous data strictures (hashes and arrays) so useful I'm now not sure when *not* to use them. They've even started to show up when I write [one liners like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17643714/2019415). There are many good guides to using references in `perl` ([and discussions here on SO for example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17414364/2019415)) - experience and familiarity seem to be deciding factors on when and how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for my $synset ( @synsets ){
    my @words = @$synset;
    print "@words\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a list of references to lists, since Perl doesn't allow lists in a list.

```
@sentences = ();
...
    # in the loop:
    push @sentences, \@words;
```

To access individual words you can then do the following:

```
$word = $sentences[0]->[0];
```

The arrow can be omitted in this case though.